# I'm trying to make a button in c# windows form app that when i click on it it show a picture i want

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I've this assignment that im supposed to do a which is a `c#` `wfa` that contains 2 buttons one labeled as "show head" and another for "show tail" and when I click on of them it should shows the picture of it

I've added 2 buttons, labeled them and added 2 picture boxes then I looked it up. I found, I should in every button write the code like this.

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Properties.Resources.Head);
```

But it give me error says that I cannot convert from `system.drawing.bitmap` to `string`

note: I've added the pictures in the resources

Comment: Its complaining that you are trying to turn a bitmap into a string, so it looks like `Properties.Resources.Head` is an image rather than a string.  Could that be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image.FromFile` method accepts a file path in `string` form. while you an image bitmap itself in resource (and not a location of the image present in local/remote directory)

refer this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

So for solution part, instead of

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Properties.Resources.Head);
```

try this

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Head
```